# Dynamic array of observables run in series with switchMap function run once all finished even if some fail

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to build a list of observables dynamically, then execute these observables one after the other and once they have all ran I need to then call another function (i.e. check if there are still any "offlineJobs" and then return true or false), this function should run even if some or all the observables have failed.

Currently, I have the following but this does not seem to work:

```
updateOfflineJobs(): Observable<boolean> {

return this.jobsLocal.getOfflineJobIds().pipe(
  switchMap(jobIds => {

      // Create array of observables to update each offline job
      const observableArray: Observable<any>[] = [];
      jobIds.forEach(jobId => {
         observableArray.push(this.updateJob(jobId, appUser));
      });

      return from(observableArray).pipe(
        concatAll()).pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
            // Check offline jobs again to make sure none still dirty
            return this.jobsLocal.getOfflineJobIds();
          }),
          map(stillDirtyJobIds => {

            return stillDirtyJobIds.length === 0;
          }),
      );
    }
  }),
  catchError(e => {
    return of(false);
  })
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of piping a central `catchError` at the end, you could pipe in each observable in the array with it's own error handlers. And from the error handlers return an observable that won't trigger the `error` callback of the subscription (I am using RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant).

Try the following

```js
import { EMPTY, ... } from 'rxjs';

updateOfflineJobs(): Observable <boolean> {
  return this.jobsLocal.getOfflineJobIds().pipe(
    switchMap(jobIds => {
      const observableArray: Observable <any> [] = [];
      jobIds.forEach(jobId => {
        observableArray.push(
          this.updateJob(jobId, appUser).pipe(
            catchError(error => {                  // <-- each observable has it's own error handler
              // handle error
              return EMPTY;
            })
          )
        );
      });

      return from(observableArray).pipe(
        concatAll(),
        switchMap(_ => this.jobsLocal.getOfflineJobIds()),
        map(stillDirtyJobIds => stillDirtyJobIds.length === 0),
        catchError(e => {
          return of(false);
        })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I still need the central catchError just in case the first "getOfflineJobIds" failed so that it still returns false? Basically I always want it to default to returning false if any sort of failure as it is vital that it doesn't return true if there are still any offline jobs (i.e. if any or all of the "updateJob" calls fail).

Comment: @trfletch: In that case yes, you do need the `catchError` at the end. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This appears to hit the second "getOfflineJobIds" within the last "switchMap" in your example after the first "updateJob" has ran rather than after they have all completed, none of my "catchError" are hit during this time.

Comment: I added "toArray()" after "concatAll()" which seems to have got it working.